# Crash on MediaController.show()

Tags: android, tabs, mediacontroller

i've a problem with mediacontroller, this part of code works perfecty on different devices as Acer Liquid (gingerbread), Archos 43 (froyo) e Archos 32 (froyo)...

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView); 
File filevideo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/edizionitsm/firenze/map_" + map_n + "/",filename + "_" + language + ".mp4");
Uri video = Uri.fromFile(filevideo);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

...but on a Point of View Pro Tab2 (gingerbread) it crash at the beginning of the activity.

```
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edizionitsm.archeoplayer/edizionitsm.archeoplayer.Player}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.widget.MediaController.disableUnsupportedButtons(MediaController.java:640)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:674)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:631)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.widget.VideoView.start(VideoView.java:962)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at edizionitsm.archeoplayer.Player.onCreate(Player.java:48)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    ... 11 more
```

the problem is in the function show() of mediacontroller class. How can i resolve it?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the line of code and all of the relevant code here: edizionitsm.archeoplayer.Player.onCreate(Player.java:48)?

Comment: The problem is here: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 14:12:59.640: E/AndroidRuntime(31433):    at android.widget.MediaController.disableUnsupportedButtons(MediaController.java:640)`. I get the same exception (on Android 4.0.3), but only when I explicitly call mediaController.show(). If not, it works, but does not show the media controller automatically - only if I touch the video, but at least there's no crash then.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem on 3.1 Honeycomb and used setMediaPlayer to resolve it.  Try your code in this order with setMediaPlayer.

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

File filevideo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/edizionitsm/firenze/map_" + map_n + "/",filename + "_" + language + ".mp4");
Uri video = Uri.fromFile(filevideo);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```